# Rewrite Url in ASP .NET MVC 3 - add *.html suffix to links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, url-rewriting

I'm creating simple application, some kind of portfolio. I've heard that it's better to have a *.html suffix in links, as it will get me better SEO results when indexing by Google...

Anyway, is there a way to modify default routing / rewrite url so that my links look like this (I'm using polish words that they are readable for my visitors):

```
domain.pl/index.html
domain.pl/kontakt.html
domain.pl/oferta.html
domain.pl/sklepy.html
```

And these links are translated into one controller (like **HomeController**), but the {0}, from the {0}.html link, will be used as an action name? Or even better, I would like to map {0} from Url to english action names like:

```
index.html = index action
kontakt.html = contact action
oferta.html = offer action
sklepy.html = shops action
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both the translation and suffix, you can try using [AttributeRouting](http://nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting).
With this package installed, you don't need to configure routes in your Global.asax and the controllers will be like this:

```
[GET("index.html")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[GET("/any/url/path/kontakt.html")]
public ActionResult Contact()
{
    return View();
}

[GET("oferta.html")]
public ActionResult Offer()
{
    return View();
}
```

By the way, if you want to remove the duplicated .html on each attribute, you can create your own attribute that extends GETAttribute and append the .html. This would be useful if you have lots of pages to configure.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure about better SEO results, but adding suffix is simple as

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{action}.html",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

Just add .html suffix to action parameter placeholder.

For translation, you could use
[ActionNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx)

```
    [ActionName("kontakt")]
    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

With both codes above combined, you get `domain.pl/kontakt.html` mapped to `Home/Contact` action.